# My websites are not visible from Apache on localhost

Tags: apache-httpd, php

I have installed Ubuntu-based Mint Mate 17.2 distro. I have configured to my taste. Everything is working fine.

I have also installed Apache, PHP and MySQL individually using `sudo apt-get install`. It is also working very well.

I have set my `/var/www/html` folder writable. Now whenever I create any folder and php files in `/html` folder I can easily browse from Firefox.

But whenever I try to copy my PHP projects from Windows 8.1/XAMPP/public_html folder to `/var/www/html` they become invisible to web.

I can see my folder and files in file manager, but can't see them through Web browser. Please help me how do I set my privileges. I also find the same problem whenever I try to upload project to cpanel on my hosting server. I am not new to Linux, but am also not an expert too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you copy the folder you should set permissions as follow:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/your_copied_folder
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/your_copied_folder
```

Comment: chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/your_copied_folder worked perfect for me. Thanks